# clearInterval function issue in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

need to clear the  interval if `currenttime >= deliverytime`.Now function call even  the condition is true and and countdown goes to negative.Need to stop the timer if `remainingTime` reaches to '00'.

```js
<script> 
function startTimer(duration, display) {
var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
t= setInterval(function () {
 minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
 seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

 minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
 seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

 display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

 if (--timer < 0) {
    // timer = duration;
    clearInterval(t);
 }
}, 1000);
}
function test(){
var x = new Date(); 
var h = x.getHours(); 
var m = x.getMinutes();
var dd=new Date(new Date().getTime()).toLocaleString();
var d = Date.parse(dd) / 1000;
var ct=new Date(new Date().getTime()).toLocaleTimeString();

var currenttime = d;
var alarmtime=$("#alarmHidden").val();
var deliverytime=$("#deliveryHidden").val();
var remainingTime=parseFloat(deliverytime)-parseFloat(d);
if((currenttime >= alarmtime) && (currenttime <= deliverytime)){
 var fiveMinutes =remainingTime;
 
 display = document.querySelector(\'#time\');
 startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
}
if(currenttime >= deliverytime){
 clearInterval(s);
 clearInterval(t);

}
}
var s=setInterval(function(){ test();  }, 1000); 
</script>
```

Comment: Also add `html` markup..

Comment: you can use `setTimeout` which is more better than `setInterval`

Comment: `document.querySelector(\'#time\')` will result _Unexpected token ILLEGAL_

Comment: @debin: setTImeout is something different that setInterval - what's better solely depends on your problem.